# Django query output from backwards ForeignKey relation

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a django Model, `Foo`, which has various known and consistently-named attributes (`alpha`, `beta`, ...) as well as a variable number of instances of `Bar`; `Bar` is itself a model with attributes (`name`, `value`, ...).
I can't have each `bar`'s name and value etc. as a column in the `Foo` model because there are too many of them, they have many different names, and some apply to only a few foos.
So I have a ForeignKey relationship within the `Bar` model, so each `bar` knows which `foo` it belongs to, and I can use Django's `select_related()`, e.g.:

```
foos = Foo.objects.filter(alpha__lte=10).select_related()
for foo in foos:
    bars = foos.bar_set.filter(name__in=('prop1', 'prop2', 'prop5'))
    for bar in bars:
        print '%s = %d' % (bar.name, bar.value)
```

This seems to work... but is it really the best way to organise my data with MySQL?

If I'm on the right track, I have another question: how can I speed this up? I should add that I have 2,700,000 `Foos` and 16,900,000 `Bars` in total (with indexes in place, etc.). Particularly slow is my output - I'd like to be able to write text files with columns of the properties: `foo.alpha`, `foo.beta`, `foo.bar1.value`, `foo.bar2.value`, etc...
where `bar1`, `bar2`, etc. are chosen by their `name` attributes. I've been experimenting with a list of output fields:

```
bar_output_fields = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop5']
all_output_fields = [('%4d', 'alpha'),
                     (%12.6f', 'prop1'), 
                     (%10.3e', 'beta'),
                     (%10.3e', 'prop2')
                     ('%2d', 'prop5')]
fo = open('output.txt', 'w')
for foo in foos:
    bars = foos.bar_set.filter(name__in=bar_output_fields)
    for bar_output_field in bar_output_fields:
        bar = bars.filter(name=bar_output_field).get()
        setattr(foo, bar_output_field, bar.value)
    for (fmt, name) in all_output_fields:
        print >>fo, fmt % getattr(foo, name),
    print >>fo
fo.close()
```

But this is extremely slow when the query returns >1000s of `foo`s.
Anyone got any suggestions for improving performance here? I've a feeling I'm missing something big...

Comment: Check out what SQL is being generated here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running
I think you may be executing a lot of sql queries, and you may actually get much better performance by doing some things in Python

Answer (score 0):

If you're only using `Foo` to limit `Bar`, then you can make it more efficient simply by cutting out `Foo`.

```
bars = Bar.objects.filter(foo__alpha__lte=10, name__in=('prop1', 'prop2', 'prop5'))
```

Comment: Alas, I need my foo properties (alpha, beta), along with a subset of their bar properties.

Answer (score 0):

Also according to the documentation if model Foo(models.Model): bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar) , then both model Foo and model bar get  model_set attribute. i.e. you could call Foo.bar_set.all() to retrieve all bars associated with foo and vice versa for Bar.foo_set.all()